# Inserting unique value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tables: I have 3 tables 
They are cust, new_cust, old_cust
all of them have 3 columns, they are id, username, name
each of them have possibilities to have same data as the others. 
I would like to make "whole" table that consisting all of them but only the uniques.

## I've Tried

### Creating a dummy table

I've tried to create the dummy table called "Temp" table by

```
select * 
into Temp 
from cust
```

### insert all table to dummy

Then I insert all of them into they Temp table

```
insert into temp
select * from new_cust

insert into temp
select * from old_cust
```

### taking uniques using distinct

After they all merged I'm using distinct to only take the unique id value

```
select distinct(id), username, fullname
into Whole
from temp
```

it did decreasing some rows

## Result

But after I move it to whole table I would like to put primary key on id but I got the message that there are some duplicate values. Is there any other way?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not a function**, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Skip those redundant parentheses and simply write `select distinct id, username, fullname ...` to make the code clearer.

Comment: thank you for the reminder, i try to do it still no change to the row number

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (All as formatted text, not images.) Also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: @yuliansen . . . Sample data and desired results would help.  What do *you* mean by "duplicate"?  What if the values change for a given id among the three tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want unique *id*s.  And you want these prioritized by the tables in some order.  If so, you can do this with `union all` and `row_number()`:

```
select id, username, name
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by priority) as seqnum
      from ((select id, username, name, 1 as priority
             from new_cust
            ) union all
            (select id, username, name, 2 as priority
             from cust
            ) union all
            (select id, username, name, 3 as priority
             from old_cust
            )
           ) c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
insert into temp
select * from new_cust

UNION

select * from old_cust
```

Union will avoid the duplicate entries and you can then create a primary key on ID column

Comment: i've tried using it before, the row result always the same as my first tried, any other recommendations?

Comment: @yuliansen there is no case that UNION will return duplicates, so I guess you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this below query...**

```
WITH cte as (
      SELECT id, username, NAME, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.username, t1.name ) AS rn   
      FROM cust t1
      LEFT JOIN new_cust t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
      LEFT JOIN old_cust t3 ON t2.Id = t3.Id
    )
    SELECT id, username, NAME
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn = 1
```

**Note:-**
Put all the query inside a CTE(**Common table expression**) 
with a new column(rn) that you will use to filter the results.

This new Column will produce **ROW_NUMBER()**....PARTITION BY username,name.....

Answer (score 1):

> But after I move it to whole table I would like to put primary key on
>   id but I got the message that there are some duplicate values.?

That's because You are trying to insert ID value from each of the tables to Whole table.
Just insert username and name and skip ID. ID is IDENTITY and it **MUST** be unique.

Run this on Your current Whole table to see if You have duplicated Id's:

```
select COUNT(ID), username
from whole
GROUP BY  username
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
```

To get unique customers recreate table Whole and make ID col IDENTITY:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.Whole') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Whole;
CREATE TABLE Whole (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), Name varchar(max), Username varchar(max))
```

Insert values into Whole table:

```
INSERT INTO Whole
SELECT Name, Username FROM cust
UNION 
SELECT Name, Username FROM new_cust
UNION
SELECT Name, Username FROM old_cust
```

Make ID col PK.

Answer (score 1):

What does Unique mean for your row ?

If it is only the username, and you don't care about keeping the old ID values,
this will favor the new_cust data over the old_cust data.

```
SELECT  
    ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY all_temp.username) 
,   all_temp.* 
INTO dbo.Temp
FROM 
(
        SELECT nc.username, nc.[name] FROM new_cust AS nc   
    UNION
        SELECT oc.username, oc.[name]
        FROM old_cust AS oc
        WHERE oc.username NOT IN (SELECT nc1.username FROM new_cust AS nc1) --remove the where part if needed
) AS all_temp

ALTER TABLE dbo.Temp ALTER COLUMN ID INTEGER NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE dbo.Temp ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

If by Unique you mean both the username and name then just remove the where part in the union